# ios 5 how to hook lockscreen notification alert with slider?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, jailbreak

All !

What class i have to hook lockscreen notification alert with slider ?

no luck with:

```
%hook SBAwayController

    - (BOOL)activateAlertItem:(id)item
    {
        %orig;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SBAwayController" message:@"activateAlertItem" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return YES;
    }

    -(void)_pendAlertItem:(id)item
    {
        %orig;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SBAwayController" message:@"_pendAlertItem" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

%end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do this by hooking SBBulletinModalController/SBBulletinBannerController class, addBulletin method

Answer (score 0):

Lockscreen Notification are either shown through push notification or local notification.you can find a lot of tutorial on the same. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) you will find local and push notification programming guide by apple.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answer, but i'm looking for private API to hook